# I just wanna access my List ? How do I access it and print the data in it

Tags: flutter

I tried `initstate` but it won't work and I don't know how to access the list I made. I just want to add all the data send to this file in `cartId` and store it in `cartid` , then I want to print it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  final int cartId ;
  const Cart(this.cartId,{Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Cart> createState() => _CartState();
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  List<int>? cartid;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    cartid!.add(widget.cartId.toInt());
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold (
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cart'),
      ),
      body: Text(cartid != null ? '${cartid!.length}' : "Empty"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to print it in terminal, or want to display it on screen?

Comment: Initialize cartid, `List<int> cartid = [];`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access the list that you didn't create anywhere. Try to do this:

```dart
class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  final int cartId;
  const Cart(this.cartId,{super.key});

  @override
  State<Cart> createState() => _CartState();
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  List<int>? cartid;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    cartid = [widget.cartId];
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold (
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Cart'),
      ),
      body: Text(cartid != null ? '${cartid!.length}' : "Empty"),
    );
  }
}
```

In the example above, we're instantiating the list in the `[widget.cartId]`. There are many ways to do that, tho.